# Unity UI - Scaling with Screen - Horizontal Layout Group within a ScrollView

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, canvas, scrollview

I am building a mobile game with a simple UI that scrolls between worlds.  My setup is
[the child structure of canvas set to expand to screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWhSs.png)

On some aspect ratios, it [looks fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igSWn.png)

But when I use a weirder one, like iPad6, the [content does not fill the screen as I would expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pua24.jpg).

I think I am missing something fundamental with how I am setting up my screen scaling. The canvas is [setup with a scalar at 50/50 width/height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg4t7.png). I tried playing around with 100/0, and 0/100, but nothing gives me quite what I need. Any pointers would be appreciated.

[Worlds GameObject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiCFV.png)

[ScrollView GameObject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qu3fH.png)

[Viewport GameObject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUaWq.png)

[Content GameObject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4ZuQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

Replace size 600x800 with 1280x720

You must use stretch for everything inside the canvas
Like this :

[image]

It must be used correctly. You can search on YouTube for how to use it

Comment: Tried this and it didn't really do much for the scaling of the content in the horizontal layout group.

Comment: You must use stretch for everything inside the canvas

Comment: I will add a picture for clarification

Comment: I am doing all of this already. It doesn't do what I expect it to do.

Comment: Can you add an image of the object "Worlds" image of the RectTransform highest thing

Comment: I have added inspector images of Worlds to Content